# Writing to SQL database with PHP on checkbox onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, checkbox

I've been using PHP, MS SQL, and HTML to build a tool for my work, I have most of it working but now I've built a report to be used with my data that I want to be able to write back to the database from an on-click event of checkboxes.

From the research I've done it suggests that I need to use Javascript to do this, I have little to no experience with JavaScript. What I've found for tutorials show it when there is only one checkbox or if there are multiple it's something that is run after the fact.

The report I am trying to get to work writes 6 columns out for all database entries that do not have a date in the "sent" field and a checkbox, there may be 1 item, or there may be 200 of them at any given time. What I want is to click that checkbox and automatically trigger a PHP script that updates that line item with today's date in the sent column. My code is not right, I am certain I have glaring issues with how I have or am calling the script, but here is what I have.

Javascript:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function issent(cb){

    if($(cb).is(":checked"))
    {
        $.getScript("sentscript.php?EID=33");
    }
}
</script>
```

I've hardcoded the entry I'm trying to check off in the script for testing and it's still not working, ultimately I want EID=$EID[$i] (or the js equivalent since thats just how I'd use it in PHP)

PHP/HTML:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr><td>
        <input type='checkbox' onclick='issent(this)' name='sent[$i]' value='" . $row['EID'] . "'/>
       </td></tr>";
    $i ++;
}
```

This does nothing on click, so I'm sure I've made a mess of it somewhere, but I can't figure out where and the questions I've read give little to no explanation and modifying the answers hasn't worked.

EDIT: this was an issue in my called PHP file where I failed to include my database connection in sentscript.php as I assumed it would carry from the original page like it does for files using include() in PHP. I still do not understand how to pass the variable from the line checked to the script but now that I know it works I can shift my focus to that.

Comment: how do you know it's not doing anything? are you checking network-tab in dev-tools? Have you added a callback function to `getScript()` to check what that script is returning?

Comment: I'm monitoring the output of the php file it's calling and it does not appear to be triggering at all let alone outputting anything. I honestly know less then what is required to be dangerous when it comes to java, I've never used it at all before and other then this function I don't intend to use it for anything else (yet).

Comment: how or where do you monnitor the output of the php? right now you would not see anything, no matter how much your php sends.

Comment: My PHP writes to a database, but it was in fact the problem in why the above failed because I failed to take into account that the open database connection did not carry over to the called PHP file like I expected. The code here works as is, I just focused on what I do not understand as being the problem, thinking I had what I do understand correct.